# present viewController open like like popup dialgo in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have menu. I have to navigate from one viewController to another viewController. But destination viewController is open like pop up dialog.I don't know why it shows.I did not adjust.  Here is the image
[image]

Here is the code i have used for navigate one source viewController to destination viewController

```
       let mainstoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewcontroller = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Search_Mobile_Number") as! Search_Mobile_Number
        let newFrontController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: newViewcontroller)
        self.present(newFrontController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please help me why it is open like dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Change the modalPresentationStyle

```
let newFrontController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: newViewcontroller)
newFrontController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(newFrontController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 if you use present() method to show viewcontroller it’ll open like dialog only you can change fullScreen to      overCurrentContext.. you can change in storyboard also.